# Is my guppy pregnant? It's my first fish so i don't know

Tags: health, aquarium, fish, animal-handling, pregnancy

Is my guppy pregnant? I really hope it is but I'm not sure... [image]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Please use every time first the search function at the top of our page :) There you would find with "guppy" and "pregnant" around 20 answers and questions about this topic. I will mark yours as duplicate and it will be linked to a similar question with a good answer. If you have more questions, or something is not clear for you, or your question is not the same as the linked one, then please let us know.

Comment: In general you should consider to get another shape of tank. The sphere shaped glass bowls give no orientation for the fish. They have some organs to measure solid surfaces and the distance to them (enables the swarms to act like one fish) but the inside of this spheres are in a way shaped, that the organs will get really confused and the fish will suffer from this lack of orientation.

Comment: Please see linked questions about guppies and platies; I linked these about platies as well, because both guppies and platies belond to the same _Poeciliidae_ family of live-bearing fish and are really similar in that aspect.